# How can I group objects with the same name using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, electron

Using Node, I'm implementing a ID3 tag parser to get the title, album, and artist from MP3's.

Now, I need to take the information I've gotten back, and group them by album name.

In my specific usage, I'm trying to go from

#### This:

```
[
  { 
    title: 'Break You',
    artist: 'Lamb Of God',
    album: 'Ashes Of The Wake' 
  },
  {
    title: 'An Extra Nail For Your Coffin',
    artist: 'Lamb Of God',
    album: 'Ashes Of The Wake' 
  },
  {
    title: 'Envy And Doubt',
    artist: 'Sever The King',
    album: 'Traitor' 
  },
  {
    title: 'Self Destruct',
    artist: 'Sever The King',
    album: 'Traitor' 
  },
  ...
]
```

#### To this: (pseudo code)

```
[
  'Ashes Of The Wake'{
    {
      title: 'Break You',
      artist: 'Lamb Of God'
    },
    {
      title: 'An Extra Nail For Your Coffin',
      artist: 'Lamb Of God'
    }  
  }
  'Traitor'{
    {
      title: 'Envy and Doubt',
      artist: 'Sever The King'
    },
    {
      title: 'Self Destruct',
      artist: 'Sever The King'
    }
  },
  ...
]
```

What would be the best way to do this?  I'm relatively new to JS, so it may be simple.

Comment: underscorejs has groupBy if you want to use that. your desired output is invalid javascript fyi.

Comment: Is this actual data? I don't believe 'An Extra Nail For Your Coffin' is from that album. :)

Comment: @JesseKernaghan You had me worried that my ID3 parser was broken! :)  But after looking it up, the song is on Ashes of the Wake

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

> The `forEach()` method executes a provided function once per array element.

```js
var data = [{ title: 'Break You', artist: 'Lamb Of God', album: 'Ashes Of The Wake' }, { title: 'An Extra Nail For Your Coffin', artist: 'Lamb Of God', album: 'Ashes Of The Wake' }, { title: 'Envy And Doubt', artist: 'Sever The King', album: 'Traitor' }, { title: 'Self Destruct', artist: 'Sever The King', album: 'Traitor' }],
    grouped = {};

data.forEach(function (a) {
    grouped[a.album] = grouped[a.album] || [];
    grouped[a.album].push({ title: a.title, artist: a.artist });
});
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(grouped, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```
var output = input.reduce(function(result, value) { 
  result[value.album] = result[value.album] || []; 
  result[value.album].push({ title: value.title, artist: value.artist });
  return result; 
}, {});
```

Answer (score 1):

As Kieran suggested, using [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) provides you an easy elegant solution.

```
var groupedData = _.groupBy(data, 'album');
```

Here's the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/a7DhxpGx0C4FVMgIjzPY?p=preview

### Edit

I would like to add that you would want to use [lodash](https://lodash.com/) instead of underscore if you are working with Node.js

Answer (score 0):

> OBS: 'Ashes Of The Wake' and 'Traitor' should be arrays, not objects, because they have multiple children.

You don't have to, but in case you want to use `underscore`, as @Daniel said, you can use the `groupBy` function.

```
var data = [
  { 
    title: 'Break You',
    artist: 'Lamb Of God',
    album: 'Ashes Of The Wake' 
  },
  {
    title: 'An Extra Nail For Your Coffin',
    artist: 'Lamb Of God',
    album: 'Ashes Of The Wake' 
  },
  {
    title: 'Envy And Doubt',
    artist: 'Sever The King',
    album: 'Traitor' 
  },
  {
    title: 'Self Destruct',
    artist: 'Sever The King',
    album: 'Traitor' 
  }
];
var groupedData = _.groupBy(data, 'album');
console.log(groupedData);
```

Will output:

```
[
  'Ashes Of The Wake': [
    {
      title: 'Break You',
      artist: 'Lamb Of God'
    },
    {
      title: 'An Extra Nail For Your Coffin',
      artist: 'Lamb Of God'
    }  
  ],
  'Traitor': [
    {
      title: 'Envy and Doubt,
      artist: 'Sever The King'
    },
    {
      title: 'Self Destruct',
      artist: 'Sever The King'
    }
  ]
]
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5se0mh60/)

Comment: Thanks for the solution!  I'm really quite new to JS, so I didn't know that objects couldn't have multiple children.  That's good to know!

Answer (score 0):

In vanilla JavaScript, you can employ [`Object.groupBy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/groupBy) with an object.

```
Object.groupBy(MUSIC_TRACKS, ({ album }) => album)
```

Here's an example:

```js
const MUSIC_TRACKS = [{
    title: 'Break You',
    artist: 'Lamb Of God',
    album: 'Ashes Of The Wake'
  },
  {
    title: 'An Extra Nail For Your Coffin',
    artist: 'Lamb Of God',
    album: 'Ashes Of The Wake'
  },
  {
    title: 'Envy And Doubt',
    artist: 'Sever The King',
    album: 'Traitor'
  },
  {
    title: 'Self Destruct',
    artist: 'Sever The King',
    album: 'Traitor'
  }
]

const groupedAlbum = Object.groupBy(MUSIC_TRACKS, ({ album }) => album)

// If you want to remove the "album" property from each object in the nested structure, 
// you need to take another iteration.
for (const key in groupedAlbum) {
  groupedAlbum[key].forEach(obj => {
    // Delete the "album" property from each object
    delete obj.album;
  });
}

console.log(groupedAlbum);
```